# T-SQL - Sum Qty based on matching data from two different columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I hope someone can help me. I'm just beginning to get my head around T-SQL and so far so good but this one escapes me...

I want to create a view for a report that consists of location and total usage however my database has this concept of some locations depending on other locations for ordering purposes. Some locations are 'Normal' meaning they do not follow this logic.

In the below example I have the primary and its two dependant secondaries.

| Location | Type | PrimaryLocation | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Primary | Null | 1 |
| 02 | Secondary | 01 | 1 |
| 03 | Secondary | 01 | 1 |
| 04 | Normal | Null | 1 |

What I need to do is sum the usage for each Primary and Normal locations where by any secondary locations that match the primary location are rolled up as usage for the Primary

This would mean my view would look something like this

| Location | Type | PrimaryLocation | Usage | True Usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Primary | Null | 1 | 3 |
| 02 | Secondary | 01 | 1 | null |
| 03 | Secondary | 01 | 1 | null |
| 04 | Normal | Null | 1 | 1 |

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when primarylocation is null
             then sum(usage) over (partition by coalesce(primarylocation, location))
        end) as trueusage
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2a0d55c74b11e7ad606ba5bca7dad19a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. This works when ran on its own but my view also contains columns of aggregated data such as other sums and I'm getting errors because its not contained in a group by clause

Comment: @kl130183 . . . As the db<>fiddle demonstrates, this answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: I was able to figure this out using your assistance. Thanks a lot !